# Modal Disappears Quickly + Bootstrap + Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'd like to start with saying I've searched and searched for the solution to my problem -- and after trying everything I read -- no success. I just want to make a simple modal to pop up when a user clicks on a link (that isn't ready yet).

---Already Tried---

1. Made sure there wasn't a second bootstrap javascript file (especially in header)
2. Tried variations in javascript syntax
3. Tried variations in the link html

When I made the link a "button" then the modal was fine -- but I don't want a simple link to be a button.

```js
$("body").on("click","#empty",function(event){
    $("#myModal").modal()
})
```

```html
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="empty">Our Blog</a></li>
```

I also tried

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#empty").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
```

I suspect there's something wrong in the way the html is set up (since the modal worked for a "button" but wont for a regular link)

Let me know if you need more clarification -- Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working modal... It may be helpful for you...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
('#myModal').modal('show');
</script>

<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click Here</a></li>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

otherwise try this code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#empty").click(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
});
```

Comment: I removed the  id="____" part from the <a> tag and finally the modal works as I want! Thanks!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your link "isn't ready yet" when you initiate the modal with Javascript it won't work.
Assuming that your link is created dynamically you have to make sure you initiate it once it is in the DOM, in a JS callback or however your link is created (instead of the Document.ready function).

Also worth noting that to initiate the default triggering (setup in the html with the 'data-' attributes) you simply use:

```
$("#myModal").modal();
```

But if you want to trigger it manually in a onClick function, you'll need to add 'show' or 'toggle:

```
$("body").on("click","#empty",function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
)};
```

Again, both of these codes needs wrapping up in a document.ready function or a callback when your link is in the DOM.